# Модуль socket выдает странный айпи адрес

Tags: python, сокет, сетевое-программирование

Вызываю
`print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))`
В выводе пишет какой-то непонятный айпи адрес. Проверил свой айпи через dnsleaktest.com - не совпал. Что за айпи мне выдал сокет? Он точно не локальный.

Comment: Ну начать стоит с логичного вопроса — что возвращает gethostname?

Comment: какой то неизвестный мне айпишник, а по идее должен возвращать тот который указан на dnsleaktest

Comment: Я так понимаю что айпи который на dnsleaktest это от моего провайдера. А питон дает адрес комании в сша DoD Network Information Center. Как сделать так чтобы питон мне выдал мой айпи? Желательно сразу и локальный, и глобальный

Comment: Знать глобальный айпи технически невозможно, его знает только ваш интернет-провайдер, который собственно и выдаёт вам доступ в глобальную сеть. А что за дичь у вас с локальными айпи, пока что непонятно

Comment: Ну так я глобальный айпи посмотрел на специальных сайтах, а сокет выдает айпи который никак со мной не связан. Вот есть допустим какое то веб приложение на питоне. Там же пользователя не заставляют вручную айпи вводить? Так какой мне метод использовать, чтобы узнать свой айпи адрес? А лучше чтобы был сразу и айпи который локальный в подсети, и который от провайдера

Comment: «Там же пользователя не заставляют вручную айпи вводить?» — очень даже заставляют, просто обычно айпи привязывают к какому-нибудь домену, чтобы пользователю было удобнее вводить буковки вместо циферок

Comment: Я имел ввиду: как приложение на питон добывает айпи адрес устройства, на котором оно запущено?

Comment: А зачем приложению его добывать? Вот например у меня на личном сервере примерно тридцать приложений, но ни одному из них не нужно знать какие-либо айпи для работы

Comment: Мне просто стало интересно как в программе получить собственный айпи в локальной сети. В каких-нибудь программах для связи в подсети такая функция может потребоваться. Если роутер поменяет айпи устройства например не вручную же каждый раз прописывать?

Comment: Так в локальной или глобальной? И не забываете ли вы учесть, что локальных айпи может быть десятки? Вот прямо сейчас на моём домашнем компьютере я могу насчитать 9 разных локальных айпи, не считая локалхост (впрочем, несколько глобальных тоже иногда бывает)

Comment: Так мне уже про глобальный все расписали. Я просто спрашиваю про то как мне через модуль сокет получить адрес в домашней сети. А вы мне рассказываете что на один компютер можно поставить 9 разных айпи

Comment: Что такое «домашняя сеть»? Что делать в ситуации, если ноутбук подключен одновременно по Ethernet-кабелю и по Wi-Fi к двум разным роутерам, например?

Comment: Так эта питон программа должна запускаться на устройствах которые находятся в одной локал сети иначе работать не будет. Причем здесь разнообразие интерфейсов?

Comment: Ну так что программе делать, если локал сетей целых две?

Comment: У меня одна и эта программа только для меня и только для моей одной локальной сети

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib import request

def send_get_request(url):
    response = request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read().decode('utf8')

url = 'https://dnsleaktest.com'
r=send_get_request(url)
pos=r.find('Hello')

print(f" Мой внешний адрес в интернете {r[pos+6:r.find('<',pos)]}")
```

Показывает адрес с сайта dnsleaktest.com
Советуют использовать модуль request, но его нужно устанавливать.
Локальный проще узнать через операционную систему.

Comment: Неужели в socket не реализован метод для получения айпи в глобальной сети?

Comment: Наоборот в urllib реализован запрос к сайту, а в socket нужно все прописывать самому, соединение, отправить запрос, шифрование если https, получить ответ, декодировать, обработать.